# Can someone explain this syntax in C#?

Tags: c#, syntax

When creating objects in Java I'm used to the following syntax:

```
objectX1 = new ObjectX(some arguments);
```

While looking over a project in C# I came across the following code:

```
_createSample = new Func<SampleBase>[]
{
    () => new SkeletonMappingSample();
}
```

I need two things explained to me.
First, how does creating an object without the brackets and parameter list and instead using {} with expressions work?

Next, what does the expression between the {} mean?

Comment: The collection initializer syntax (or an equivalent anyway) exists in Java too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you found:

```
_createSample = new Func<SampleBase>[]
{
    () => new SkeletonMappingSample();
}
```

Is just a notation for creating an array and then initialising it with values.

Which is effectively the same as:

```
_createSample = new Func<SampleBase>[1];
_createSample[0] = () => new SkeletonMappingSample();
```

Except that in the `{ }` version the bounds are set by the compiler based on how many elements you've added between the `{ }`

For objects:

```
SomeClass abc = new SomeClass()
{
   SomeProperty = "SomeValue",
}
```

Is just a way of creating an object and then setting some property values, it's effectively the same as:

```
SomeClass abc = new SomeClass();
abc.SomeProperty = "SomeValue";
```

Answer (score 1):

This code creates an array of [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) : `_createSample = new Func<SampleBase>[]`

Then it instantiates one [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) `() => new SkeletonMappingSample()` as the sole element in it, using [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) (note the braces, and the semicolon is optional):

```
{
    () => new SkeletonMappingSample();
}
```

This expression will instantiate a new SkeletonMappingSample when called :

```
var newMappingSample = _createSample[0]();
```

Comment: It's a "collection initializer" not an object initializer.  They're two entirely different things.

Comment: This only goes so far as to explain that it's creating an array of func then includes additional unnecessary information about lambdas and the such, the question was simply about how the syntax works for initialising an array from a given set of items.